# React.js with Play Framework - Server-side rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, playframework, nashorn

If I am using [Facebook React](https://github.com/facebook/react) with [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) and I want to pre-render my DOM server side and send pure HTML to the client, how would I do that?

While researching possibilities, I looked at [webjars](http://ticofab.io/react-js-tutorial-with-play_scala_webjars/), [react-play](https://github.com/ssorallen/react-play), and [scalajs-react](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react).

I like [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) for search engine optimization reasons because the way the page is organized, going from one page to another is basically just swapping out one or more rectangular components for another one.

Comment: I'm slightly confused... `react-play` seems to do exactly what you want, so i'm not sure what you're asking...